# Mouse and Keyboard Stop working randomly

Tags: usb, keyboard, 22.04, mouse

I have a Dell  Precision 8520 and I've been running Ubuntu on it starting with 18.04 and now with 22.04.
For a long time I had an issue where it would occasionally not wake from sleep. I then discovered that it happens because somehow the mouse and Keyboard (both USB) have stopped working. About a year ago, this issue went away until about a month ago, but this time it's worse: The keyboard and mouse stop working randomly (i.e. I'm halfway through typing a chat message and it just stops typing). I don't know which software update brought it back, but it's a productivity killer.

Is there a solution to this?
I know USB is not completely dead because a test phone I have connected to the box is still showing in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1973:0019 Spectralink Corporation Versity
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The only way to get out of this is a reboot. While this is going on, I can ssh into the box and everything else works.

For those about to suggest replacing the KB/Mouse, I've replaced both. For the past few months I've had a KVM and when this happens, the KB/Mouse work without issue on the other machine.

Checking `dmesg` I have a bunch of errors that seem relevant:

```
[238321.762101] usb 1-8.3: USB disconnect, device number 7
[238321.874047] usb 1-8.4: USB disconnect, device number 13
[238323.969295] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[238324.278385] usb 2-9: new SuperSpeed USB device number 77 using xhci_hcd
[238329.601353] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[238329.706195] usb 2-9: new SuperSpeed USB device number 77 using xhci_hcd
[238334.977313] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[238335.090315] usb usb2-port9: attempt power cycle
[238336.018324] usb 2-9: new SuperSpeed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
[238341.377324] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[238341.482154] usb 2-9: new SuperSpeed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
[238346.753334] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[238347.062371] usb 2-9: new SuperSpeed USB device number 79 using xhci_hcd
[238352.385342] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[238352.490131] usb 2-9: new SuperSpeed USB device number 79 using xhci_hcd
[238357.761339] usb 2-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[238357.874456] usb usb2-port9: unable to enumerate USB device
[238357.882179] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 73
[238357.882187] usb 2-8.1: USB disconnect, device number 74
[238357.986208] usb 2-8.3: USB disconnect, device number 75
[238358.002136] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[238363.518120] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[238387.942254] usb usb2-port8: attempt power cycle
```